# Having problems with pointers and recursions

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, recursion

I am right now doing a problem about the Collatz sequence. I have to find the longest Collatz sequence if we start with a number in the range 1,...,1000000. The Collatz sequence of a number n is defined as:
if n mod 2 == 0 then the next number is n/2. If n mod 2 != 0 then the next number is 3*n+1. The sequence for n=10 is 10,5,16,8,4,2,1.

Of course if we do this problem the naive way, we would calculate the Collatz sequence of each number n between 1,...,1000000 and check which has the longest sequence. This is not efficient though.

A smarter algorithm would be to use the fact that given a Collatz sequence, the sequence obtained by not looking at the first few elements, is also a Collatz sequence. So if we calculate the sequence for n=10 i.e. 10,5,16,8,4,2,1 then the sequence 5,16,8,4,2,1 is also a Collatz sequence and we have immediately found the length of the Collatz sequence for n=5,n=16,n=8,n=4,n=2 and n=1 by just calculating the sequence for n=10.

With this idea in mind, I wrote the following code in C using pointers and recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int recursion(int n, int *array){
    if((*array)[n]==0){//check if I already have the length of the sequence for this n
        if(n/2==(double)n/(double)2){//check if n mod 2 == 0
            (*array)[n]=recursion(n/2,array)+1;
        }       
        else{
            (*array)[n]=recursion(3*n+1,array)+1;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int length[100];//this array will contain the lengths of sequences,
    //I will only do it for n=1 up to n=10, but I have to have a bigger 
    //array since the Collatz sequence elements can be higher than 10
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        length[i]=0;
    }
    length[0]=1;//the Collatz sequence for n=1 has length 1
    for(int n=1; n<=10;i++){
        recursion(n,&length);//use the function for each n
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n",length[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code, I get several errors:

```
main.c:5:13: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
    if((*array)[n]==0){
       ~~~~~~~~^~
main.c:7:12: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                    (*array)[n]=recursion(n/2,array)+1;
                    ~~~~~~~~^~
main.c:10:12: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                    (*array)[n]=recursion(3*n+1,array)+1;
                    ~~~~~~~~^~
main.c:25:15: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (*)[100]' to
  parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            recursion(i,&length);
                        ^~~~~~~
main.c:4:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'array' here
int recursion(int n, int *array){
```

I don't know why I get these warnings and errors.

Comment: Start at (oops) 626331?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array` is an `int*`. `*array` therefore is an `int`. You can't say `int i; i[0]`, so why would you be able to say `(*array)[0]`?

Just access it normally, by saying `array[n]` instead of `(*array)[n]`.

Also, in your `main` function , call `recursion` with `recursion(n, length);`, not `recursion(n, &length);`. You're passing the array, not a *pointer* to the array.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to call the function like this

```
recursion(n,length);
```

Since, the array name contains the address of the first element of the array.

And you are receiving it also in a `pointer to int`. Therefore you can use `array[]` in the function normally. Like `array[n]`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `*(array + n)` or `array[n]` instead of `(*array)[n]` to access the `n`th variable.
2. Since `length` is an array, calling the function with just the name passes it address.
3. Small error in for loop. `for(int n=1; n<=10;i++){` to `for(int n=1; n<=10;n++){`

These changes fix the compilation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int recursion(int n, int *array){
    if(*(array + n)==0){//check if I already have the length of the sequence for this n
        if(n/2==(double)n/(double)2){//check if n mod 2 == 0
            *(array + n)=recursion(n/2,array)+1;
        }       
        else{
            *(array + n)=recursion(3*n+1,array)+1;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int length[100];//this array will contain the lengths of sequences,
    //I will only do it for n=1 up to n=10, but I have to have a bigger 
    //array since the Collatz sequence elements can be higher than 10
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        length[i]=0;
    }
    length[0]=1;//the Collatz sequence for n=1 has length 1
    for(int n=1; n<=10;n++){
        recursion(n,length);//use the function for each n
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n",length[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```